# Oracle trigger execution on a particular condition

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

My requirement is that I have a table where there are 4 columns(val1,val1_date,new_val1,new_val1_date) in it.

The issue is that when new_val1 gets updated along with new_val1_date,I need to update columns val1,val1_date accordingly.

For that I have created a function.

Now when  new_val1_date is equal to sysdate then I want to execute the trigger.
My trigger is not giving me proper result.

Can anyone help me in that.

```
create or replace TRIGGER MY_Trigger
     AFTER INSERT  OR UPDATE ON my_table 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (TO_DATE(NEW.new_val1_date,'dd/mon/yyyy')<=TO_DATE(sysdate,'dd/mon/yyyy'))
declare
    V_CD_ERROR NUMBER; 
    V_DS_ERROR VARCHAR2(500);

begin
    My_UpdateProc(V_CD_ERROR,V_DS_ERROR);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('V_CD_ERROR: ' || V_CD_ERROR || ' V_DS_ERROR ' || V_DS_ERROR);
end;
```

Comment: What error(s)/result(s) do you get? What do you have within the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle Date columns store the timestamp, so unless your inserted value matches sysdate down to the second, it won't have the expected result.

You need to "trunc" the dates so the timestamp is set to midnight for both values. Then it will evaluate based on the date.

Also, the evaluation should be done inside the begin/end block of the trigger.

```
create or replace TRIGGER MY_Trigger
     AFTER INSERT  OR UPDATE ON my_table 
FOR EACH ROW
declare
    V_CD_ERROR NUMBER; 
    V_DS_ERROR VARCHAR2(500);

begin
  if (trunc(NEW.new_val1_date) = trunc(sysdate)) then
    My_UpdateProc(V_CD_ERROR,V_DS_ERROR);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('V_CD_ERROR: ' || V_CD_ERROR || ' V_DS_ERROR ' || V_DS_ERROR);
  end if;
end;
```